# How can I enter an email address into text input field in Edge using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have the following program:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            var driver = new EdgeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.cornelsen.de/shop/registrieren-lehrer");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("dummy@user.de");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this in Chrome or any other browser aside from Edge, then the email adress is entered correctly. But if I try the same thing in Edge, the "@" character is missing. The field displays only "dummyuser.de".

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: trying typing slowly.

Comment: Tried it. No effect.

Comment: Check if you can type "@" manually.

Comment: Of course I can. This is a general problem with edit fields in Selenium with Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't as easy as I thought after all. Issues with alecxe's answer:

1. `arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '...');` works only the first time you call it. After calling `element.Clear();`, it doesn't work any more. Workaround: `arguments[0].value='...';`
2. The site doesn't react on the JavaScript call like it would on `element.SendKeys();`, e.g. change event is not invoked. Workaround: Send the first part of the string up to the last "forbidden" character via JavaScript, the rest via WebElement.SendKeys (in this particular order, bc if you do another JavaScript call to the same field **after** SendKeys(), there will occur no change event either).

I also realized that there are more "forbidden" characters in Edge, e.g. accented or Eastern European ones (I'm Central European). The problem with 2. is that the last character might be a forbidden character. In this case, I append a whitespace. Which of course affects the test case behavior, but I haven't had any other idea.

Full C# code:

```
public static void SendKeys(this IWebElement element, TestTarget target, string text)
{
    if (target.IsEdge)
    {
        int index = text.LastIndexOfAny(new[] { '@', 'Ł', 'ó', 'ź' }) + 1;
        if (index > 0)
        {
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor) target.Driver).ExecuteScript(
                "arguments[0].value='" + text.Substring(0, index) + "';", element);
            text = index == text.Length ? Keys.Space : text.Substring(index);
        }
    }

    element.SendKeys(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can set the `input` value directly via `ExecuteScript()`:

```
IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string script = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'arguments[1]');";
js.ExecuteScript(script, email, "dummy@user.de");
```

---

Or, what you can do is to *create a fake input element* with a predefined value equal to the email address. Select the text in this input, copy and paste into the target input.

Not pretty, but *should only serve as a workaround*:

```
// create element
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string script = @"
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'text';
    el.value = 'arguments[0]';
    el.id = 'mycustominput';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
";
js.ExecuteScript(script, "dummy@user.de");

// locate the input, select and copy
IWebElement myCustomInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("mycustominput"));
el.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");  // select
el.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "c");  // copy

// locate the target input and paste
IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
email.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v");  // paste
```

Comment: Your first approach is almost cool. Only thing is that you can spare the `argument[1]` and have `dummy@user.de` in the string directly: `arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'dummy@user.de');`

IT WORKS!!! THANKS SO MUCH!

You will get the bounty.

Comment: @Kimmy good to hear that. Yeah, I just wanted the email to come from outside of the script, just in case you will need to have it configurable. But, yes, you can have it hardcoded into the script as you've shown. Thanks.

Comment: In fact the email address is loaded from XML, but I pass it directly into `setAttribute()` and not to the JavaScript, e.g. `"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', " + myEmailString + ");"`. But it's very cool to pass in the web element as an argument. I didn't know this technique.

Answer (score 0):

This problem used to occur in old browsers. Apparently it returned in `Edge`.

You can try sending the string in pieces

```
IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
email.SendKeys("dummy");
email.SendKeys("@");
email.SendKeys("user.de");
```

Or try using `@` ASCII code

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("dummy" + (char)64 + "user.de");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added one extra line to click on text field and then send keys, I tried this and its working for me.
Code is written in java, you can change that to any other, if you want.

```
//INITIALISE DRIVER
WebDriver driver = null;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to("http://www.cornelsen.de/shop/registrieren-lehrer");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//CLICK EMAIL FIELD, JUST TO HAVE FOCUS ON TEXT FIELD
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("dummy@user.de");
```

Comment: You are using `FirefoxDriver`. My problem is with Edge, not with Firefox. My sample code works fine in Firefox, even without your extra `click()` before `sendKeys()`.

Comment: I meant, you can try the same logic with edge also, let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: It works with or without extra click in Firefox and it doesn't work with or without extra click in Edge.

Comment: Can you try this: 1. Apply explicit wait until email is clickable 2. Click on it 3. Then type it. If I am understanding correctly, you could type email till dummy but not after that ??

Comment: No effect! The email field contains "dummyuser.de" only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the Text field first.

try following

`driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).clear().SendKeys("dummy@user.de");`

Comment: Nope! BTW, I posted the entire source code, so you can try yourself before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Copy Paste?

```
Clipboard.SetText("dummy@user.de");
email.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: It *would* help, but unfortunately I have to be able to run the test case on a remote Win10 machine, too.

Comment: Why it wouldnot work on remote win10 machine? Since it's the script itself, it should work the same way no matter test environment is (remote, local, CI, etc ...)

Comment: Because if I put a string in the clipboard, then it will be in the clipboard of the machine that runs the test case, not of the machine where I remote-control the browser.

Comment: It's not true, Kimmy :). It should set clipboard for the remote control (if you run it remotely); and it should set clipboard local (if you run it locally)

Comment: Really? I have to try. But for this problem, I'm using the JavaScript workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the Program Manager for WebDriver at Microsoft. I just tried to reproduce your issue on my home machine (Windows 10 build 10586) and couldn't reproduce. Your exact test entered the '@' symbol fine.

You should check if you have the latest version of Windows 10 and WebDriver. If you hit the Windows key and type "winver" and hit enter it'll open a popup with the Windows version info. You want it to say

Microsoft Windows
Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.104)

This is the latest version of Windows 10 released to the public. If you have this version you'll also need the corresponding version of WebDriver found here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49962

Note that if the build is 10240 that you're on the original release build. Our November update added substantial support for new features (like finding elements by XPath and more!) along with bug fixes which might explain your issues.

Lastly I should note we have an Insiders release as well for WebDriver to match with the Insiders program. If you're subscribed to the Insiders program and want to see the newer features and bug fixes for WebDriver you can find the download here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48740

Note that it currently supports build 10547 which was actually before the November update. It'll be updated very shortly (next couple of days) to support the latest Windows Insiders flight, build 14267.

Comment: In order to use the WebDriver 2.0, I *needed* to update my Win10 to version 1511. So I am on the most current releases, definitely. Why is the "insiders" WebDriver older than the official one? Looking forward to the next version.

Comment: It was older (it's not updated) because none of the new flights contained updates to WebDriver, so there wasn't a reason to update it for the newer builds. Going forward it will be updated with every release as we've streamlined the process and new insiders builds should have bug fixes for WebDriver.

If you go to the insiders link now it has the newest build (14267) and if you have the equivalent Windows Insiders installed you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I not agree with the last comment (Program Manager for WebDriver at Microsoft). I can reproduce the problem. This is my configuration:

Target Machine (Hub node where tests are run):
  Win 10 build 10585.104
  MS Edge 25.10586.0.0
  MS EdgeHTML 13.10586

Selenium framework:
  SeleniumHQ (for Java): 2.48.0

I am using Selenium Grid to run my suite. In this case, I was only doing conceptual test of Egde implementing a basic test:
1. Start Hub in local machine (Win 7) opening console (administrator privileges)
2. Register Node in Hub in target remote machine (Win 10 build 10585) opening console (in this case without administrator privileges because in other way edge hangs when create new session).

Setting up my grid and checking that everything is ok when I try to write my account name in login page I can not see the @ and my basic test fails (wrong credentials).

I have introduced @ by hand in the moment edge is opened (interrupt point) and I can see symbol.
I have sent "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" to the text field and I can not see any. In summary, I have tried many things and I can not see @

When I started with Web Automation Testing using Selenium (Java) I remember this behaviour in old versions of Firefox and Chrome. I not really sure which one but it was reproducible in old version.

This partial basic code (implementated with pageobject) IS WORKING with Firefox 35.0 and Chrome 48.0.2564.109 but NOT IS WORKING with Edge's version I put at the beginning of my comment.

WebElement element = WebDriverExtensions.findElement(context, By.cssSelector("input[name='username'][type='email']"));

element.clear();
element.sendKeys(email);

Front Developers are using AngularJS and are validating user's text input to match with a welformatted email:

I afraid that current Edge version does not support sendkeys with this kind of character, maybe the problem is front on-line validation and Edge has to suits these situations because they are really common.

Best regards

Comment: ganesh already proposed the `.clear()` thing, but it doesn't work in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me with the version 2.52. This worked for me :

```
 EdgeDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver("folder of my edge driver containing MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = _edgeDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
 js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('Email').value = 'some@email.com'");
```

Make sure to replace the ".getElementById('Email')" with what you should use to find your field with javascript and replace the "folder of my edge driver containing MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" with the correct path.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm using 2.52, too. Your approach is almost exactly the solution I posted on Feb 18 at 15:25 (the accepted answer), only that you locate the element within JavaScript, whereas I locate it *before* the JavaScript call and then pass it in as an argument to the JavaScript, which is cleaner in my opinion. But that's probably a matter of taste! I'm using Selenium PageFactory for locating all my elements, so your approach would be a consistency breach in my context.